# Does nagios XI support notifcations based on a threshold percentage of the number of services in a hostgroup that are in a critical state?

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, notification

Say there's a hostgroup defined on a Nagios server; and that hostgroup has a notification set up to go off when a certain service or services reach a critical state then a notification email will be sent out to a contact stating that it should be looked at.  Does this sort of functionalty exist in Nagios XI?

Comment: What about this isn't basic nagios functionality built into every version of nagios?

Comment: @chicks I guess my question about it is how do I access that functionality?  Or what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Hostgroups and Servicegroups are for grouping objects in the web interface, and for simplifying configuration (in core, anyway) by allowing services, escalations, dependencies, etc., to be assigned to groups.

What you're describing sounds more like [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start) or possibly `check_cluster` (see [docs page](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/clusters.html) about monitoring clusters for more info).